# Eclipse JFace/SWT ViewerFilter select never gets called

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I'm trying to build a simple dialog with a `TableViewer` in it, along with a checkbox which would filter the data. However the table is empty and the filtering never gets done. Whats wrong with this code?

```java
public class AsTestDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

private Table table;

private AsTestFilter filter;

private TableViewer tableViewer;

public AsTestDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
}

@Override
 public void create() {
     super.create();
     setTitle("Table Test");
 }

 @Override
 protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
     Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
     area.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

     tableViewer = new TableViewer(area, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
     table = tableViewer.getTable();
     table.setHeaderVisible(true);
     table.setLinesVisible(true);
     table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

     TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
     TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
     tblclmnNewColumn.setWidth(130);
     tblclmnNewColumn.setText("Column1");

     TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn_2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
     TableColumn tblclmnId = tableViewerColumn_2.getColumn();
     tblclmnId.setWidth(150);
     tblclmnId.setText("Column2");

     Composite composite = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
     composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));

     Button btnFilter = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
     btnFilter.setBounds(10, 10, 111, 20);
     btnFilter.setText("Filter");
     btnFilter.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("CHECKBOX SELECTED");
            filter.setFilterType("foobar");
            tableViewer.refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}

     });
     addTestData(table);
     //Filter
     filter = new AsTestFilter();
     tableViewer.addFilter(filter);
     tableViewer.getTable().pack();
     tableViewer.refresh();
     return area;
 }

 private void addTestData(Table table) {
     TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
     item1.setText(new String[] {"1","2"}); 
     item1.setData("1");
     TableItem item2 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
     item2.setText(new String[] {"3","4"}); 
     item2.setData("3");
 }
}
```

The filter class:

```java
public class AsTestFilter extends ViewerFilter {

private String filterType = "all";

public void setFilterType(String tp) {
    this.filterType = tp;
}

@Override
public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {
    System.out.println("SELECT CALLED: "+filterType);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JFace `TableViewer` you must use a 'content provider' set with

```java
tableViewer.setContentProvider(provider);
```

and then call

```java
tableViewer.setInput(input data);
```

creating `TableItem` objects directly will not work properly as `TableViewer` expects to create these objects itself.

If you have a simple array or `List` of objects the content provider can simply be:

```java
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
```

and the set input:

```java
tableViewer.setInput(array or list);
```

Your filter is not called because you have not called `setInput`, the table viewer does nothing until this is called.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I guess that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewerFilter` operates on the `TableViewer`'s input, which will be null in your case as you aren't using `tableViewer.setInput(model)`. Instead you are creating `TableItem`s directly.

You will need to set up a content provider, label provider, and define a model which you can pass to `.setInput` for the table viewer, and remove the function which directly creates the `TableItem`s.

Once you do this, the `ViewerFilter` should work.

There are plenty of tutorials around which describe this, including https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html and http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets